# Low-power options for powering RPi for long period of time

Tags: power

I want to put an untethered RPi in the middle of a field and let it check and log the temperature for a **week or more at a time**.

If I wanted to run off of a rechargeable battery to wake up every hour, check and log the temp, then go back to sleep, would I be able to keep it running for a few days?

Is it possible to use a combination of a small button cell battery (or similar) to keep it running/ alive while asleep and a larger battery to operate when awake?

General specifics:

- Pi Zero or Pi 2B
- temperature sensor
- some kind of lipoly battery or AA battery
  pack

If I wanted to add another sensor, like a simple light sensor, would it have a major impact on battery life?

Comment: Wouldn't an arduino or other microcontroller that supports low power/sleep modes be a better option than a Pi?

Comment: Probably - like a Trinket? What would you recommend?

Comment: TI makes a very low power launchpad (ti.com/launchpad) would be my first choice.

Comment: Since a non-Pi solutions seems to be more appropriate to check http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ instead. Be sure to not push the Pi-reference though, otherwise they might just migrate it back here.

Comment: @SteveRobillard, beat me to it. I was just about to suggest the [MSP430](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430) turns out your launchpad is based on that series.

Comment: I would add that they have a fantastic tutorial series on the wiki for the launchpads that cover the low power modes. They even have a version http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-msp430-msp-exp430fr5969.html#tabs that can run off a super cap.

Comment: Thanks, all. This looks promising: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeoOz9DoxKE. Sorry for the non-Pi spam.

Comment: There is nothing to be sorry for.

Answer (score 2):

A low-power microcontroller seems to be more suited for this task, given the desired runtime in the field of a week or more. A Pi will not last that long, see [Powering the Pi with 2 AA batteries](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29902/powering-the-pi-with-2-aa-batteries)

One example of suitable microcontrollers would be the [MSP430](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430) based TI-launchpad. It has a fantastic tutorial series on the wiki for the launchpads that cover the low-power modes. They even have a [version](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-msp430-msp-exp430fr5969.html#tabs) that can run off a super cap.