# Alternate power methods

Tags: power, power-supply

I have an embedded zero I'd like to power from a battery pack with 4 AAs. I know I can connect the leads the the GPIO as well as cutting apart a cable to plug in but I am wondering if I could solder them to the pads underneath the power plug.

These ones: (pp5 and pp2)

[image]

So do these lead to power? If so which is positive and which is negative?

Comment: I would use a Monk Makes RaspPiRobot Board V3 to power my pi with batteries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [source](https://web.archive.org/web/20210225030803/http://hackers.gallery/841/misc/raspberry-pi-zero-pad-probing) lists the test pads of the Pi Zero and their function as follows:

> PP1   USB +5V Input
> PP6   GND
> PP8   3.3V

The [official schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/RPI-ZERO-V1_3_reduced.pdf) (see top left corner) also list PP5 as GND.

[image]

Powering the Pi from AA batteries itself has been discussed before (such as buck/boost converters to adjust the voltage), e.g.:

- [Powering the Pi with 2 AA batteries](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29902/powering-the-pi-with-2-aa-batteries)
- [more](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=power%20aa)

Without proper voltage regulation connecting the batteries might pose some issues during discharge of the batteries - voltage is too high with fresh batteries, too low on empty batteries.